# passing data value to ui-grid

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to pass the data value  ui-grid.I need to pass $scope.ll value to ui-grid.If I copy the data and assigned  $scope.ll=[{}] Id and statesum_totalcount are working well. I need to pass $scope.ll to grid

My data in array are as

```
{
"ID": "3",
"stat_sum": {
    "totcount": 3
},
"zip_stats": [
    {
        "zip": "560045",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "zip": "567657",
        "count": 2
    }
],
"qual_stats": [
    {
        "count": 1,
        "qualification": "B.E."
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "qualification": "BE"
    }
],
"prof_stats": [
    {
        "count": 1,
        "profession": "Doctor"
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "profession": "Software Engineer"
    }
],
"city_stats": [
    {
        "city": null,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "count": 1
    }
],
"state_stats": [
    {
        "count": 1,
        "state": "Karnataka"
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "state": "Kerala"
    }
],
"stats_info": [
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "fgdfgd",
        "question": "comment-about-me-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 1,
        "answer": "one",
        "question": "radio-answer-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 2,
        "answer": "two",
        "question": "radio-answer-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "t-shirt",
        "question": "select-any-dress-for-me-[]"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "no",
        "question": "say-yes-or-no-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "2015-09-25",
        "question": "select-your-b.date-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "24",
        "question": "select-your-age-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "2",
        "question": "type-number-"
    },
    {
        "acount": 3,
        "answer": "false",
        "question": "select-true-or-false-"
    }
]
}
```

In controller

```
 $timeout(function () {
     console.log($scope.ll);    //works fine
        $rootScope.showspinner = false;
        $scope.gridOptionsComplex = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            showGridFooter: true,
            showColumnFooter: true,
            columnDefs: [

                {name: 'ID', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
                {name: 'stat_sum.totcount', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
                {name: 'zip_stats.zip', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
                {name: 'zip_stats.count', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
                {name: 'qual_stats.qualification', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
                {name: 'qual_stats.count', width: 100, enableCellEdit: false,},
            ],

     data:$scope.ll
        };
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.aut = true;
        });
    }, 500, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same kind of problem I faced ,I am giving an example code how to solve this

```
{
"result": {
    "fileNames": [
        "Book1 (2).csv",
        "address_sample (3).csv",
        "Book1.csv"
    ],
    "ids": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
},
"responseSuccess": "success",
"responseError": null,
"responseInfo": null,
"responseWarning": null,
"responseCode": 0
}
```

I have output like above format and also I have to Integrate with these in to ui-grid .

example **controller side code** once the control reached success part I am getting the output as the format of above , so lets see how to integrate with ui-grid,

In my controller I have `$scope.gridsOptions` like

```
$scope.gridsOptions = {
columnDefs : [
    {
        field : 'field',
        name : 'Id'
    },
    {
        field : 'filename',
        name : 'FileName'
    }]
 }
```

I assumed the control came to the success part `.success(function())` what ever validate could you please validate then,

```
.success(function(data){
$scope.resultValues =[];

// Here My PD(Problem Domain says iterate based On `ids`)
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.ids.length; i++) {

       // Im getting each ID in  $scope.fileId variable
       $scope.fileId = data.result.ids[i];

      // Here Im getting each fieldNames in  $scope.fileName variable 
      $scope.fileName = data.result.fileNames[i];

      //Then I am pushing those values in to fieldId
      $scope.resultValues.push({
                        field : $scope.fileId,
                        filename : $scope.fileName
                });
      }

      ListData.fileIdValues = angular.copy($scope.resultValues);

      // I am pointed  those to $scope.gridsOptions.data
      $scope.gridsOptions.data = ListData.fileIdValues;
})
```

Please **Note**   `ListData.fileIdValues` in my code it is angular **service** variable `this.fileIdValues ={}`. For my Problem Domain I need these values so I stored it in `service`and use it where ever I want.

Comment: can you please explain sir.

Comment: Could you please tell Which part ?

Comment: how can I modidy columnDefs : [] to my array value sir and how to use data.result.ids.length

Comment: Hi I am also not fluent in english  . So I thought you are asking How to use data.result.ids.lenght . Am I right ?

Comment: ya and also I need to add fields in colDef[]

Comment: If wanna add field's in `colDef : []`  is simple man , just follow above example .like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92824/discussion-between-sakthi-and-user3386779).